# Centering Text Vertically with Image

Tags: html, css, image

I have tried several of the solutions posted on Stack Overflow, as well as others that I found on Google.

I am attempting to get some text to align vertically-centered alongside of an image.

The page in question is located [here](http://tinyurl.com/lgm4dzg).

Near the bottom of the page, there is text that reads: "*Integers are rational numbers because they can be written in the form:*", followed by an image. The image always floats up and off to the side, instead of being centered inline with the text. I want it to appear as if the image is typed inline with the text.

I originally had the text and image in a paragraph, but based on the solutions I found on Stack Overflow, I moved the text and image into a div, and assigned some CSS to it:

```
    vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;
```

I also tried various other methods that were suggested:

```
    vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;
```

This single image isn't a huge deal, but I plan on having many pages with math problems. When I have pages with multiple images, I think it's going to look really bad.

So far none of the other threads have fixed my specific issue.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

```css
img{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
This is some text <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wplIb.png">
```

Specifically on your page, using a Developer tools of choice you can play with the result:

[image]

Comment: It looks like I needed to target the image, instead of trying to align the text. It appears to be working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

one solution put use table with with 2 cell in each one of them make the vertical aignment to middle

Comment: I'm not sure that would work in this case, because some of the pages are going to have a lot of math formulas. I would have to layout all of my pages using tables. I just need to put small images inline with the current sentence. Thanks.